# Convert list encasing inside data frame row values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas Series that has list elements in each row.
I want to de-list those values and store them back in the series.
It looks like this. Can someone please help?

```
0                           ['Harvard business review']
1                           ['Harvard business review']
2     ['Journal of Medical Marketing: Device, Diagno...
3                           ['Harvard business review']
4                    ['Science Translational Medicine']
5                    ['Science Translational Medicine']
6                                       ['Tetrahedron']
7                                       ['Tetrahedron']
8                                           ['bioRxiv']
9                                           ['Science']
10                                     ['Cell Systems']
11                                       ['Prescriber']
12                                             ['Cell']
```

I tried to convert each into a list and then extract the values, but it would not convert to list.

Comment: It is just giving me the first character. It does not consider the list inside each row. It sees it as Object type

Comment: pubmed_ids_greater_than_one['journal'].dtype
dtype('O')


pubmed_ids_greater_than_one['journal'].str[0]
0     [
1     [
2     [
3     [
4     [
5     [
6     [
7     [
8     [
9     [
10    [
11    [
12    [

Comment: This worked :D Thank you very much.

Comment: glad. can you the consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
import ast
df['column_name']=ast.literal_eval(df['column_name'])
df['column_name'].str[0]
```

Or if the type is a object you can try:

```
df['column_name'].str.extract('(\[(.*?)\])',expand=False)
```

Comment: @user11233789 yes, provided you dont have the `'`, does this work `df['column_name'].str.extract('(\[(.*?)\])',expand=False)` its always better for these type of questions if you provide the dataframe constuctor eg `df.to_dict()`